# Wordpress how to make toggle menu toggled on

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, toggle

I would like to make the menu links visible (I don't have many of them) when on mobile device.
Is there a way to have the menu toggled on by default?
I'm using twenty thirteen WP theme This was working until sometime recently, maybe an update changed things?

I am not very knowledgeable with jquery but I put this code into my header's head but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> 

// Toggles small menu
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( '#site-navigation' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
} );

</script>
```

OR maybe there is some other way?

Here is some of the css I used with the elements:

This is some css that I have put in currently:

```
.nav-menu li a {
    padding: 7px 20px!important;
}

.menu-toggle {
    display:none;
}
.toggled-on {
display: block;
}

.toggled-on .nav-menu, .toggled-on .nav-menu > ul {
float: right;
padding-bottom: 7px;
width: 150px;
}
.toggled-on .nav-menu li a:hover,
.toggled-on .nav-menu ul a:hover {
    background-color:#FFF!important;
    color: #df3926;  /* WEBSITE RED */
}
```

EDIT:
Solved it! I put the jquery code above into the footer and wrapped it with jQuery(document).ready(function($) and now it's calling it and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you could create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo that'll be great.

Second, my guess is, your **.toggled-on** class doesn't have **display: block;** on it. So try doing this:

```
.toggled-on {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here's the site where I'm trying this. If you reduce the size of the site, you'll see that the menu disappears. I left the toggle "Menu" visible just for now. I'd like to make it invisible and make the actual menu links be visible right away:
http://www.grantarchitecturestudio.com/
I have edited the question above to include the css info. Not sure if I can do a jsfiddle if I don't have WP running behind.

Comment: Solved it! I put the jquery code above into the footer and wrapped it with jQuery(document).ready(function($) and now it's calling it and working

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you were able to figure it out